# Securing Sidekiq and other admin content with Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, sidekiq

How would it be possible to secure the Sidekiq admin page (and other content etc) behind my existing Active Admin authorization system (i.e. AdminUser)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Active Admin but you probably have a model `admin` in your app in order to authenticate admins.

I do have a similar admin model (Devise) and the below code in `routes.rb` does the trick for me :

```
require 'sidekiq/web' 
authenticate :admin do 
mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq' 
end
```

If you have more to protect, especially admin related controllers, I suggest creating a namespace and authorizing your admins for every controller in the namespace.
(It is probably possible to force authenticate admins for the whole namespace also, just like above)